# Should I hide or show this implementation?

Tags: c++

An animation is composed of frames. I have the following class:

```
class Frame
{
private:
    sf::IntRect rect;
    unsigned int duration;

public:
    Frame(sf::IntRect rect, unsigned int duration);

    unsigned int getDuration();
    sf::IntRect& getRect();
};
```

At the animation class I have the following function:

```
void Animation::addFrame(sf::IntRect rect, unsigned int duration) // public
{
    frames.push_back(Frame(rect, duration)); // ps: private std::vector<Frame> frames;
}
```

should it actually be:

```
void Animation::addFrame(Frame frame) // public
{
    frames.push_back(frame);
}
```

thus showing how animation is implemented underneath?
I'm also in doubt if the frame class shouldn't simply be a struct with rect and duration. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never lie in your code. If you say: addFrame, I expect that passing Frame should be absolutely fine. The first function you have to provide as this class' interface is addFrame(Frame const&). Then, if you firmly believe that having the (IntRect, uint) overload is really useful when writing real client code, add this overload. But (Frame const&) should go first (I mean when you think whether or not).

BTW, I'm not sure what the Frame is, but you should consider passing it by constant reference - that's idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have the addFrame take a Frame&

Keeps the interface simple, and then if your frames become more complex, you won't have to make as many changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a matter of taste. for my preference, i would choose

```
void Animation::addFrame(sf::IntRect rect, unsigned int duration) // public
{
    frames.push_back(Frame(rect, duration)); // ps: private std::vector<Frame> frames;
}
```

because it hides the implementation.

Writing class is good(again this is my preference) when you have member variables(which should be kept private usually).